# Android: How to disable content surfaceview position update in Android 7.0

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-video-player, android-7.0-nougat

I had a app which is video playing using SurfaceView.
We have a quick hack to hide some part of the video content by doing videoSurfaceView.setScaleY(0.5) which able to hide bottom part of content.
Check those images

[Original before scale happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAuvl.png)

[Expected result after scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKr1X.png)

In Android 7:
"A SurfaceView object's content position is now updated synchronously with the containing app content" , From google developer  link: developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#surfaceview

So in android 7, the content inside was scaled perfectly. Yeah it sure a bug fix for more of apps and reduce developers pain.

But I don't want it. How to disable this scaling feature?
Such as: videoView.setScaleContentIfChange(false)

Comment: what you tried. Please share your code.

Comment: `
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mVideoView, View.SCALE_Y, 1, 0.5f);
                oa.setDuration(1000);
                oa.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                oa.start();
`

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mVideoView, View.SCALE_Y, 1, 0.5f); 
oa.setDuration(1000);
oa.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); 
oa.start();
```